# seems to block /my-beautiful-sef-url-123

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I have robots.txt that looks like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /system/
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /index.php
```

The obvious goal has been to prevent all the ugly URLs from being indexed, as they all begin with "/index.php".
But for some reason all URLs like */my-beautiful-sef-url-123* are listed under **Crawl errors** in Google Webmaster Tools with "URL restricted by robots.txt". (When I test such URL it yields *Allowed* for both Googlebot and Googlebot-Mobile.)

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the URLs like */my-beautiful-sef-url-123* real pages or do they do a redirect to another page? If they do a redirect, maybe try testing the redirected to page in Google Webmaster??